# OAuth invalid signature

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, oauth, two-legged

I am having trouble with OAuthorization, I have a flash player application requesting a PHP script.
The PHP is always returning:

```
{"status":false,"message":"Invalid Signature"}
```

I tried two differents libraries:

```
https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-as3
https://github.com/iotashan/oauth-as3
```

I dont know what do try anymore, could someone help me with this?

The as3 script that is generating a wrong URL:

```
import com.yahoo.oauth.OAuthRequest;
import com.yahoo.oauth.OAuthConsumer;
import com.yahoo.oauth.OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1;
import com.yahoo.oauth.IOAuthSignatureMethod;
import com.yahoo.oauth.OAuthToken;
import com.yahoo.oauth.OAuthUtil;

var signature:IOAuthSignatureMethod = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
var consumer:OAuthConsumer = new OAuthConsumer("myKey", "mySecret");

var oauthRequest:OAuthRequest = 
    new OAuthRequest(
        "GET", 
        "http://mySite.com/index.php",
        null, 
        consumer, 
        null
    );

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(oauthRequest.buildRequest(signature));

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getComplete);
loader.load(request);

function getComplete(event:Event):void
{
    trace("data", URLLoader(event.currentTarget).data);
}
```

I have a example did in PHP script that generate a correct URL:

```
<?php
// include oath
require_once('OAuth/OAuth.php');

if ($mode == 'generate')
{
    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer(OAUTHKEY, OAUTHSECRET);
    $sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1;

    // call this file
    $api_endpoint = $_GET['url'];

    //use oauth lib to sign request
    $req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, null, 'GET', $api_endpoint, $parameters);
    $sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
    $req->sign_request($sig_method, $consumer, null); //note: double entry of token
    echo $req->to_url();
    exit;
}
```

This is the url generated by the PHP script, this work:

```
http://mySite.com/index.php?
oauth_consumer_key=myKey&
oauth_nonce=20de438daf761115018b3d6f26456a6e&
oauth_signature=JpWrfU77Pl%2FfFoa%2BhVy8agq9I5Q%3D&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
oauth_timestamp=1347583047&
oauth_version=1.0
```

This is the url generated by the AS3 script, this not work:

```
http://mySite.com/index.php?
oauth_consumer_key=myKey&
oauth_nonce=b8808c76e9aaa264964aefabb22bdc55&
oauth_signature=jZ31R4C0Ybj1dluIjy6wKCtN7D4%3D&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
oauth_timestamp=1348705359&
oauth_version=1.0
```

Comment: GitHub uses oAuth v2 which doesn't require a signature.

Comment: If you are interested I have created an [oAuth lib](https://github.com/PeeHaa/PHPoAuthLib) for PHP in which GitHub works.

Comment: Thank you PeeHaa, I will suggest to the team implement a v2. Meanwhile I will try to find a v1 lib. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)

Thanks to PeeHaa that told I was using a version 2.0 library, now I am using back the iotashan lib, that is version 1.0 and it is working now :)

```
import org.iotashan.oauth.IOAuthSignatureMethod;
import org.iotashan.oauth.OAuthConsumer;
import org.iotashan.oauth.OAuthRequest;
import org.iotashan.oauth.OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1;
import org.iotashan.oauth.OAuthToken;
import org.iotashan.utils.OAuthUtil;
import org.iotashan.utils.URLEncoding;

var signature:IOAuthSignatureMethod = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();

var consumer:OAuthConsumer = new OAuthConsumer("myKey", "mySecret");

var oauthRequest:OAuthRequest = 
    new OAuthRequest(
        OAuthRequest.HTTP_METHOD_GET, 
        "http://mySite.com/index.php",
        null, 
        consumer, 
        null
    );

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(oauthRequest.buildRequest(signature, OAuthRequest.RESULT_TYPE_URL_STRING));

// Creating URLLoader to invoke Google service
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getComplete);
loader.load(request);

trace("request", request.url);

function getComplete(event:Event):void
{
    trace("data", URLLoader(event.currentTarget).data);
}
```

Comment: Mark this as the solution so that others know it is solved :)